# What does it mean "Russenfaßein"?

Tags: austrian

In an article from 1979 about seafood manufacturer [Carl Warhanek](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carl_Warhanek) ([C. Warhanek - 120 Jahre (Firmenchronik)](http://gastarbajteri.at/im/107105950479/107459990277/106422691328/107452857883/110986948256.html)) I came across the following sentence:

> (...) in Mszana Dolna (...), wo er große Buchenwälder kaufte, deren Holz zur Herstellung der bekannten Warhankenschen **Russenfaßein** diente.

**What that "*Russenfaßein*" could be?**

---

Some context:

1. In 1885 Warhanek built in [Mszana Dolna](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mszana_Dolna) a canned fish plant and I've read that the process involved storing herrings in wooden barrels. Could that "*faßein*" be related to "*Fass*" (a barrel)?
2. On Wikipedia, in an article about *[C. Warhanek](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/C._Warhanek)* company there is written:

> Die Räucherfische werden in einer speziellen **Buchenholzmischung** geräuchert.

So maybe "*faßein*" is something related to that *"mischung"*?

3. The prefix "*Russen*" could be related to something that the factory produced, as in another Wikipedia article, [Carl Warhanek](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carl_Warhanek), there is written:

> Aus dem Holz der Buchen wurden Fässer für die Produktion von Russen hergestellt.

(Note, however, that large parts of that Wikipedia article are based on the article mentioned in the question, where "*Russenfaßein*" word is present.)

---

PS I tried to Google phrases such as "*faßein*" or "*fassein*", but found no results.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you got the orthography wrong, maybe in a translation error or an OCR problem: The word should be "Russenfass[e]ln", the plural of "Russenfassl". (When looking at the linked original, what you consider an "i" clearly looks like an "l" to me)

A *[Russe](https://www.oewb.at/oebv/oewb/start.xav#__oewb__%2F%2F*%5B%40attr_id%3D%27d3e1151959%27%5D__1711021106423)* in Austrian German can obviously mean a citizen of Russia (which it doesn't here, you rarely put them into barrels...), but is also used to denote a marinated herring. Which is clearly the proper choice here.

A *[Fassl](https://www.oewb.at/oebv/oewb/start.xav#__oewb__%2F%2F*%5B%40attr_id%3D%27d3e417056%27%5D__1711021269587)*, on the other hand, is a small barrel.

So, your first assumption is right, and the text is talking about barrels for marinated fish.

Comment: Bonus points for knowing what a "Russe" is in Austria.

Comment: @tofro: Thanks! I've even found an explanation why those herrings are/were called "Russen" in Austria :)
https://www.elfin.at/schon-gewusst/haeufig-gestellte-fragen/#toggle-id-9

Comment: Dinge gibt's... wieder was gelernt. Da ess ich doch gleich 'nen Hamburger und 'nen Wiener oder Frankfurter und danach 'nen Berliner oder Donauwelle ;).

Comment: Maybe it's just a bad transcription of _Russenfäßlein_, which is even Standard German.

Comment: @phipsgabler Nah, I don't think so. There's no "German German" dialect that would denote a herring with "Russe", that's a definite Austriacism. Even in Bavaria, Austria's closest neighbour region, where the term "Russ" is known, that's an entirely different thing (a drink made of Weißbier and lemonade, which you **could** easily put into barrels, but the context doesn't ask for drinks)

Comment: @phipsgabler: look at the picture linked and you can clearly see the word "Russenfaßeln" in the text. "-el", "-erl" (in dialect also "-al") are replacement suffixes for "-lein" or "-chen" in German High German, signifying diminutives. e.g. "Lercherl" is a small specimen of a "Lerche" (lark, Alaudidae). in German High German this would probably be a "Lerchlein".